# Excel - List of locations column: Comparing, how to pull out what is missing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I need top pull out the missing locations from a list, is there a simple way to do this.  I have failed thus far.
Example: There is an image here for a sample.  I need to see what's in column B that is not in column A, given a list of cities:

[image]

Comment: Show us a sample of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In **C2** enter:

=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B2)=0,"X","")

and copy down:

[image]

Because springfield is missing from column **A**